# Are MySQL @userVariables safe to use in stored procs with entity framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

As the title suggests we have a .NET app calling a MySQL db through entity framework. Several of the stored procedures declare and use MySQL user variables.
From the documentation I see that user variables are isolated to session.
What I can't figure out is how the session is isolated when using Entity Framework.
Does each EF call to the database have its own session when using the MySQL Connector? I am concerned about two calls sharing those @userVariables.

(I know I can declare regular variables in the stored proc, but it makes it had to copy sections of the proc into an adhoc query tab to test pieces. Using user variables makes it very easy to test.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL session means an open connection to the MySQL server. If your application uses connection pooling, whereby database connections may not be closed and re-opened between various calls, data in MySQL user defined variables may be shared between different application users.

However, if your application does not use connection pooling, therefore each time your code closes a connection to the database, the connection is really closed. In this case the user defined variables will not be shared between application users.

Connection pooling is managed by the datasource provider (MySqlConnection), not by EF.

Comment: Thanks. My take away is: No, they are not safe. Even if we are not using connection pooling today, someone could decide to flip that on three years from now, without know the history of everything that was written. I just wish MySQL would let you use the declare variable syntax outside of a stored proc so it wasn't so hard to troubleshoot code segments.

Comment: If the above response helped you in resolving the question, then pls mark it as accepted, so other viewers of this question know that the question is solved.